# On close of popup angular mat-slide-toggle checked property is getting removed

Tags: angular

Checked property of `mat-slide-toggle` is getting removed after closing the popup

```
<mat-tab *ngFor="let card of cards" >
  <ng-template matTabLabel>
    <span>{{card.title}}</span>                             
  </ng-template>
  <ul *ngFor="let car of card.default;let i=index">
    <mat-slide-toggle [checked]="car.type === 'true' ? true : false" (change)="onToggle(i,$event)">
        <li>{{car.name}}</li>
    </mat-slide-toggle>
  </ul>
</mat-tab>
```

Comment: I don't see any question. What is it you are struggling with?

Comment: The above code is in popup .After closing the pop up the mat-slide-toggle is getting reset.Can we save the changes after closing  the popup ?